# shell script to remove files

Tags: shell, find, cron

I'm trying to delete files older than six days, then log the files which get deleted.
So far.

In a `sh` file, I got following;

```
find /home/pi/ftp/upload -type f -mtime +6 -exec rm {} +
```

Then within `sudo crontab`

```
59 23 * * * /home/pi/scripts/cullftp.sh > /var/log/ftp/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H\%M\%S`-cull.log 2>&1
```

But when it runs at midnight, which only creates a empty file, and none of the files get deleted.

Although this bit of the code work:

```
find /home/pi/ftp/upload -type f -mtime +6
```

What is the best way to solve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Make sure the script file is executable, and has a proper hashbang line (`#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash` or such), though you should get an error if it isn't executable.

2) `find ... -exec rm` will not print anything, you'd need to explicitly tell `find` to print the filenames too, e.g.  `find ... -exec rm + -print` or `find ... -delete -print` if your `find` supports `-delete`.

3) At least on GNU find, `-mtime +6` has some interesting rounding. It first rounds the time down to full days (24 h periods), and then sees if the resulting time is strictly greater than 6. The result is that it only matches files that are at least 7*24 hours old. Using something like `-mmin +8640` would lessen the impact. (6 days * 24 h/day * 60 min/h = 8640 min)